# Compiler error C2280, attempting to reference a deleted function operator=

Tags: c++, sorting, compiler-errors

I'm programming a Monopoly game. And I really love the sort function for making nice clean outputs, in this instance sorting the properties a player owns by group.

First of all here's my property sorter function

```
bool propertySort(Property a, Property b) { return a.getGroup() <  b.getGroup(); }
```

Now, player owns a list of these properties.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Dice.h"
#include "Property.h"

class Player
{
public:
    ...
private:
    int curMoney{ 1500 };
    int curLocation{ 0 };
    int playerNum{ 0 };
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Property> ownedProperties{};
    int curDiceRoll;
};
```

As you can see it's a private attribute towards the bottom that's initalized to 0 properties.

So in my property sorter in main, where I would display the properties onto the board for the player to see, the sorter function constantly keeps giving me error C2280. I know it's precisely this sort function throwing this error, because if I comment out the sort line the program runs fine. I'm sure it's something obvious I'm ignorant of since I'm a beginner programmer. If anyone could offer insight as to what it is that would be great, thanks!

```
void viewProperties(Player& p)
{
    string prompt = "Select a player to view their properties";
    vector<string> playerNames{};
    for (Player p : players)
    {
        playerNames.push_back(p.getName());
    }
    Menu propertiesMenuSelection{ prompt, playerNames };
    vector<Property> propertiesOfSelectedPlayer = players[propertiesMenuSelection.getChoice()].getOwnedProperties();
    sort(propertiesOfSelectedPlayer.begin(), propertiesOfSelectedPlayer.end(), propertySort);

    system("CLS");
```

In case this helps here's the Property class

```
#pragma once
#include "Space.h"
#include <array>
#include <vector>

extern std::vector<Player> players;
class Property : public Space
{
public:
    Property(std::string name, std::vector<int> values);
    ~Property();
    void run(Player&) override;
    std::vector<std::string> boardOut() const override;
    std::string getName() const override;
    ...
private:
    std::string name;
    int group;
    int price;
    int buildingCost;
    int buildings;
    Player* ownerPtr = nullptr;
    std::array <int, 6> rent;
    const std::array <std::string, 10> groups{ "Brown", "Light Blue", "Pink", "Orange", "Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Dark Blue", "Railroad", "Utility" };
};
```

Here is the space class as requested very simple.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Player;

class Space
{
public:
    virtual void run(Player&) = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::string> boardOut() const = 0;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Some part of `Property` or `Space` is not assignable.  Can you include `Space` in your post please.

Comment: `giving me error C2280` -- This is a compiler error, not a runtime error, thus no error is "thrown", as the title in your question suggests.

Comment: `const std::array` -- This member variable might be why the copy is not available.

Comment: I added the space class, hope it helps figure it out!

Comment: OMG! The const std::array was causing the error, what the heck?! Why?!

Comment: Because you can't assign to a `const` variable. Silly example: https://ideone.com/AieNNX

Comment: Here is a better one with an easier-to-read error message: https://ideone.com/6RiXzJ

Comment: Now that I think about it, this is a rare case where you need an assignment operator and **don't** need [the rest of the big three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Cool. I now have an example!

Comment: @Alex -- In layman's terms, the compiler cannot figure out what you want to do with that member, since it is `const`.  [Here is an old, but related article from Dr. Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-problem-with-const-data-members/184403306)

Comment: Wow that is fascinating and useful information. Next time I'll know to use only static consts, which to be honest, that array should have been. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The deleted function is the assignment operator. `Property` cannot be assigned because the `const` member `groups` cannot be assigned. The most logical solution to this is to declare `groups` to be `static` so that all instances of `Property` share it and it does not need to be assigned. Eg:

```
static const std::array <std::string, 10> groups;
```

and storage for `groups` needs to be assigned and initialized outside of the class definition:

```
const std::array <std::string, 10> Property::groups{ "Brown", "Light Blue", "Pink", 
                                                     "Orange", "Red", "Yellow", "Green", 
                                                     "Dark Blue", "Railroad", "Utility" };
```

## TL;DR

The default behaviour of the assignment operator is to copy all of the members of the source into he destination without applying any smarts to the copy. This means a really simple example

```
class test
{
public:
    const int a = 10;
};
```

Will generate the equivalent of

```
test& operator=(const test & src)
{
    a = src.a;
    return *this;
}
```

which is not possible because `a` is `const` and cannot be changed even if there is no change.

You could add your own assignment operator

```
test& operator=(const test & src)
{
    // deliberately does not assign a = src.a
    return *this;
}
```

but the only reason you would want this is if there is no method by which you can change the value of `a` at initialization. If you cannot change `a`, then all instances of `test` have the same value of `a`, and `a` might as well be a `static` member.

Example of failure where two `test`s have a different value for `a`:

```
int main()
{
    test a{11}; // a const variable cannot be changed after initialization, 
                // but this initializes a to 11.
    test b;     // uses the default of 10

    std::cout << a.a << ',' << b.a; // output 11,10
    a = b; //this can't really be be done. a can never equal b
}
```

Comment: Perfect! What a great explanation. That static solution is exactly what I needed and implemented, many thanks!

Comment: @Alex Not a problem. Way too late to help you out, but hopefully the next person with this problem finds it.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, if other people run into this error, which can be very confusing if you are using something like sort and it comes out of no where. Hopefully, they can find this question, look at your answer. And perhaps they'll realize how dangerous unrestrained use of non-static const are. This was a great lesson for me and hopefully others too!